# editing another user's git pull request

Tags: git, github

I am new to git. how do I edit files in a pull request made by another user. The pull request is on a branch from the repo and I dont own the repo. I need to edit a couple of files that are part of this pull request. The other user has allowed me to make changes to it. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the other user allowed you to change the repo, just clone it, make the changes to the branch, add, commit, and push.

```
git clone gitolite@github.com/project
cd project
git checkout branch
# make changes
git add .
```

Depending on the owner of the repository, you might have to use `--fixup` commits, or squash your changes into the existing commits and push with `--force`.

```
git commit
git push origin branch
```

Comment: thanks. but im trying to edit a pull request, not the repo. The other user has an open pull request. I want to make changes to a couple of the files in that branch before he pushes it in.

Comment: Yes, changes made to a branch from which the pull request was opened are reflected in the pull request (and GitHub tells you so).